# How to check if a value is present on a obect inside another object?

Tags: javascript, object

I have, this object, that contain attributes where them contain object values with other attributes and values.
So, i need to create a function that allow me to pass as param that will be searched inside the object tags. I Tried to write this in es6+ but it dosent work, who can help me?

```
    const tags = {
  '1': {
'id': 'birra',
'name': 'Birra'
  },
  '2': {
'id': 'olio-aromatizzato',
'name': 'Olio Aromatizzato'
  },

};


 const getElementName = searchKey =>  {
 Object.keys(tags)
            .map(key => tags[key])
            .filter(tag => Object.values(tag).includes(searchKey))
            //return value of tags[key].name
}

const getElementID = searchKey =>  {
 Object.keys(tags)
            .map(key => tags[key])
            .filter(tag => Object.values(tag).includes(searchKey))
            //return value of tags[key].id
}


console.log(getElementName(['birra','birra2']));
```

If i pass index 0 or 1, it works, but i need to pass the entire array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
search = (data) => {  

 let searchedItems = [];
  data.map((item) => {
    for (const property in tags) {
     if(Object.values(tags[property]).indexOf(item) > -1){
        searchedItems.push(tags[property]);
     }
   };
  });

  return searchedItems;
}
 
const data = search(["Birra","123"]);
```

Comment: I cant use some, because its not compatible with ie11, but my function works, i need to pass the entire array ad param, single index works

Comment: Ok, but is the same, i need to passa in index of an array not only a value or index

Comment: You said you had to search for value initially, index of what like? 0 or 1?

Comment: console.log(getElementName(['birra','birra2']));
ok, i have a for: tag in getElementName(['birra','birra2']), how can print all matches?

Comment: i need a for loop inside my function, because indexof take only 1 element not an array of elements

Comment: @Mantegnous If you pass array in param like getElementName(['birra','birra2']) and please tell me clearly what is your desire result? what you want in return?

Comment: In this case i can pass multiple element so i can check if multiple values are present in my object and not only one

Comment: I have updated my answer please check it now it will give you the result you required

Comment: Yes it's correct, but i need to return only item, not {Birra : true}

Comment: complete item? like {
'id': 'birra',
'name': 'Birra'
  } if found?

Comment: I have updated no it will give you an array of items found

Comment: so, with two values, i'm aspect: [{ 'id': 'birra', 'name': 'Birra' }, [{ 'id': 'birra2', 'name': 'Birra2' }]

Answer (score 0):

I changed your `.filter` so it returns when the tag.name or tag.id == key. In the for loop, I check if there is a value when the function runs for each name. If it does, I add 1 to the counter.

```js
const tags = {
  '1': {
    'id': 'birra',
    'name': 'Birra'
  },
  '2': {
    'id': 'olio-aromatizzato',
    'name': 'Olio Aromatizzato'
  },

};

const getByName = (key) => {
  let elem = Object.keys(tags)
    .map(k => tags[k])
    .filter(t => t.name == key);
  return elem
}

const getByID = (key) => {
  let elem = Object.keys(tags)
    .map(k => tags[k])
    .filter(t => t.id == key);
  return elem
}

const names = ['birra', 'birra2', 'Birra', 'Birra', 'barra', 'borra', 'Birra'] // 3 times Birra (so result should be 3).
let counter = 0;
for (let n = 0; n < names.length; n++) {
  if (getByName(names[n]).length > 0) {
    counter++
    console.log(getByName(names[n]))
  }
}
console.log('Total matches: ' + counter)
```

Comment: ok, i have a for: tag in getElementName(['birra','birra2']), how can print all matches?

Comment: @Mantegnous I added a for loop to check if a match was found, is this what you mean?

Comment: @Bandy nope, i have already a for in the html that pass the value, but allow only 1 value, i need to pass an entire array

Comment: @Mantegnous so you want to only pass the ones with unique id?

Comment: i dont want to know if array names contain 3 times birra, i need to know where is contained in my object. At the moment the function works only for a value, i need to pass another value without recall the function with another index.

Comment: So, i need to check if index 0 or 1 exist in my object, if not exist return null, this now works for only a value, i need to pass multiple values

Comment: for example: getName('birra' , 'birra2) and .filter(t => t.name == key || key2); so i can check multiple values